# Sass error in Stencil JS build - Undefined function

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, node-sass, stenciljs

I have a Stencil JS project using version 2.0.3. The build is failing for the following error:

[image: Sass Error with Stencil JS]

My Node version is 4.21.0. I have played around with a couple of different Node and Node-Sass versions, but it doesn't seem to go away. This is happening after a fresh npm install, I suspect a package was upgraded somewhere and it is causing this to happen.

Please can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you added `@use("sass:map")`?

Comment: The error appears to be in the @material/theme package. Make sure you are using a version of SASS that is compatible with that package.

Comment: @Thomas I haven't added it, its inside the material package.

Comment: @G.Tranter I tried multiple of those combinations, because no clear information is available anywhere, even on the material website. After a lot of messing around, I simply cloned a branch off of an old working branch and then did an npm install. Used Node version 14.21.0.

Comment: I haven't tried them, but the instructions here look fairly detailed: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#using-mdc-web-with-sass-and-es2015.